# Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

i was programming a notepad with tkinter, but when i tried to define "createNewFile" that create before creating the new file, ask you to save, but it give me an error. Expected an indented block (, line 32). Here's the code:

```
def createNewFile():
    if len(textArea.get("1.0", END+"-1c")) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save?", "Do you wish to save the file?"):
        saveFile()

        else:
            textArea.delete("1.0",END)

def saveFile():
    file = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode='w',defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=(("Text File",".txt"), ("All Files","*.*"),("HTML Files",".html .htm"),("CSS Files",".css")))

    if file != None:
        data = self.textArea.get('1.0', END+'-1c')
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
```

Comment: Is your code actually aligned like it is here?

Comment: Please check any beginner level Python tutorial about if-else statements before asking such a question.

Answer (score 1):

The line that follows the second `if` statement in the `createNewFile()` function (i.e., `saveFile()`) needs to be indented.

```
def createNewFile():
    if len(textArea.get("1.0", END+"-1c")) > 0:
        if messagebox.askyesno("Save?", "Do you wish to save the file?"):
            saveFile()

        else:
            textArea.delete("1.0",END)
```